# Build routines for 1Byte/2Byte access based on SetPhysLong() in WinIo v3.0

Tags: windows, memory, dll, dllimport

I have one question about how to build routines for *1Byte/2Byte* access based on **SetPhysLong()** in **WinIo v3.0**.

**SetPhysLong()** is used to access memory in unit of DWORD(32bit) and my objective is to build my own routines:

- *SetPhysBYTE()* to access memory in unit of BYTE(8bit unsigned), and
- *SetPhysWORD()* to access memory in unit of WORD(16bit unsigned)

Someone told me below way can solve this problem:

1. Use **GetPhysLong** to retrieve the current DWORD contents
2. Put the new BYTE / WORD into the **correct part** of the DWORD
3. Then use **SetPhysLong** to write that back

But I think above way failed if below situation occurs:

1. Assume 4-byte register is mapped to memory 0x12345678 (because it is memory-mapped IO)
2. Assume 2nd byte of that register is the **Status register** and the attribute is *"Write 1 to clear"* and 2nd byte is 0x40 now
3. Assume we want to write 0xA5 to memory 0x12345678. Follow your way and we got:

   - use GetPhysLong then returns 0x00004000
   - put 0xA5 to LSB and we got 0x000040A5
   - use SetPhysLong to set 0x000040A5 to memory address 0x12345678

This is ***NOT*** correct because value 0x40 will be written to 2nd byte and clear it to 0x00 !!!

Thus my objective is to use SetPhysBYTE(0x12345678, 0xA5) to achieve my goal and do not influence other bytes based on below SetPhysLong()....

```
bool _stdcall SetPhysLong(PBYTE pbPhysAddr, DWORD dwPhysVal)
{
    PDWORD pdwLinAddr;
    tagPhysStruct PhysStruct;

    if (!IsWinIoInitialized)
        return false;

    if (g_Is64BitOS)
    {
        PhysStruct.pvPhysAddress = (DWORD64)pbPhysAddr;
    }
    else
    {
        // Avoid sign extension issues
        PhysStruct.pvPhysAddress = (DWORD64)(DWORD32)pbPhysAddr;
    }

    PhysStruct.dwPhysMemSizeInBytes = 4;

    pdwLinAddr = (PDWORD)MapPhysToLin(PhysStruct);

    if (pdwLinAddr == NULL)
        return false;

    *pdwLinAddr = dwPhysVal;

    UnmapPhysicalMemory(PhysStruct);

    return true;
}
```

[EDIT] I have solved this and please reference below code if need be...

```
bool _stdcall SetPhysBYTE(PBYTE pbPhysAddr, BYTE bPhysVal)
{
PDWORD pdwLinAddr;
tagPhysStruct PhysStruct;

if (!IsWinIoInitialized)
    return false;

if (g_Is64BitOS)
{
    PhysStruct.pvPhysAddress = (DWORD64)pbPhysAddr;
}
else
{
    // Avoid sign extension issues
    PhysStruct.pvPhysAddress = (DWORD64)(DWORD32)pbPhysAddr;
}

PhysStruct.dwPhysMemSizeInBytes = 1;

pdwLinAddr = (PDWORD)MapPhysToLin(PhysStruct);

if (pdwLinAddr == NULL)
    return false;

*(((PBYTE)((DWORD)pdwLinAddr))) = bPhysVal;

UnmapPhysicalMemory(PhysStruct);

return true;
}

bool _stdcall SetPhysWORD(PBYTE pbPhysAddr, WORD wPhysVal)
{
PDWORD pdwLinAddr;
tagPhysStruct PhysStruct;

if (!IsWinIoInitialized)
    return false;

if (g_Is64BitOS)
{
    PhysStruct.pvPhysAddress = (DWORD64)pbPhysAddr;
}
else
{
    // Avoid sign extension issues
    PhysStruct.pvPhysAddress = (DWORD64)(DWORD32)pbPhysAddr;
}

PhysStruct.dwPhysMemSizeInBytes = 2;

pdwLinAddr = (PDWORD)MapPhysToLin(PhysStruct);

if (pdwLinAddr == NULL)
    return false;

*(((PWORD)((DWORD)pdwLinAddr))) = wPhysVal;

UnmapPhysicalMemory(PhysStruct);

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [EDIT] part of this question !